# outer joins models that are not associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, activerecord

I have the following SQL I want to create with `activerecord`. My problem is that I am stuck in a logic loop where I can't `LEFT OUTER JOIN` a table which has yet to be joined, and I can't find my entry point to the join fiasco

in activerecord I am trying to do

```
AdMsgs.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN shows ON ad_msgs.user_id = shows.id OR ad_msgs.user_id = shows.b_id ")
      .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN m ON m.user_id = users.id OR m.m_id = shops.id OR m.m_id = shows.b_id")
      .joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON ad_msgs.to = users.email OR ad_msgs.user_id = users.id OR users.id = m.user_id")
                    .where("shows.id = ?", self.id)
                    .distinct("ad_msgs.id")
```

the query outputs an error saying it doesn't know what users is on the second join (probably since I haven't joined it yet) but I need to select the `m` records according the the users

`AdMsgs` doesn't have an association with neither of the tables.

Is there a way to full outer join these 3 tables and then select the ones relevant (or any better ways?)

Comment: This will generate invalid SQL...  Use to_sql to see this.

Comment: note the self.id which might throw an error too. This query is from the shows model

Comment: to me it looks like a DB design issue. Only thing I could think was something like joining all tables by INNER JOIN and supply all criteria in WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

use `find_by_sql` to implement such scenarios.

otherwise as a rule of thumb, if you can't use `joins` like this `Blog.joins(articles: :comments)` you are probably doing something bad or use `find_by_sql` instead.

in a complex case, i'm writing my query in SQL first to verify the logic involved. often times it's trivial to replace one complex query with 2 simple ones (using `IN(*ids)`).

Comment: is IN(*ids) efficient when there could be a lot of ids ? would rails lazy load it?